# How to stop null being printed after exiting my for loop?

Tags: java, loops, printing, null, return

So i am trying to develop a simple text based java game, of which a small part of it is the players inventory, while i am sort of winning (I'm very new to java) i cant seem to figure out how to get the null to stop printing on the screen, to put this into context, i have other methods that take care of killing enemy etc and if an enemy is killed then a dropChance() method is run, if the enemy drop anything then the players inventory is updated with the new stuff the enemy dropped, in another part of the code when the player encounters enemies, the player has 5 options, attack, defend etc etc, one of these options is to display their inventory, at this point the method below is called and works fine in printing out all the elements of the players inventory, the problem is as stated earlier, that once the for loop is finished and exits we then move to the return null and this is also printed out in the console window which is obviously not ideal, any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, if more of my code is required to gain a fuller understanding then i will gladly submit.

Thanks for any help that is offered.

D.

```
    public static List<String> getPlayerInventory()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerInventory.size(); i ++)
        {
            System.out.println(playerInventory.get(i));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

// Combat Loop.
                while (!killedAnEnemy)
                {
                    int randomEnemyAttack = random.nextInt(dungeon.getMaxEnemyAttack());
                    int randomPlayerAttack = random.nextInt(dungeon.getMaxPlayerAttack());

```
                System.out.println("\n> What would you like to do: ");
                System.out.println("\n\t * Press 1 to attack.");
                System.out.println("\n\t * Press 2 to defend.");
                System.out.println("\n\t * Press 3 to run away.");
                System.out.println("\n\t * Press 4 to use a health potion.");
                System.out.println("\n\t * Press 5 to display inventory");

                int input = scanner.nextInt();

                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("\n You attack the " + userEnemyChoice + " and strike it for " + randomPlayerAttack + " damage points!");
                        System.out.println("\n The " + userEnemyChoice + " hits you back for " + randomEnemyAttack);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("\n You decide that defense is the best option, the " + userEnemyChoice + " attacks you first causing " + randomEnemyAttack + " hit points of damage!");
                        System.out.println("\n You then attack in retaliation and strike the " + userEnemyChoice + " for " + randomPlayerAttack + " hit points of damage");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("\n You realise you are no match for this enemy and so choose to run, the " + userEnemyChoice + " strikes you one final blow" + "\n for " + randomEnemyAttack + " hit points as you turn your back and are left defenseless!");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("\n Your inventory is as follows: ");
                        System.out.println("\n\t " + getPlayerInventory());
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: Is `playerInventory` a static object?

Comment: Yes, more code is required to understand. This code does not prints the null from the return value. There could be null in playerInventory which is getting printed..

Comment: more code on the way

Comment: Also, there's no point in having a return type if you're always returning null. Either return `void` or return `playerInventory` or whatever it is you intended.

Comment: If you donot have anything to return, you can use `void` as data-type

Comment: This is the section of code that deals with the 5 choices as spoke about and it is run from my main, which is of course as you right said static, apologies if this is wrong and i should have maybe made the player inventory its own object but as stated im fairly new to java and so am just trying to grasp concepts and then worry about where stuff should be etc, anyway heres the code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your switch-case block, replace

```
System.out.println("\n\t " + getPlayerInventory());
```

With

```
getPlayerInventory();
```

This will work the way you want. The reason it was printing "null" was because you made the call inside a print method. It is not needed, as the print method inside getPlayerInventory() will work on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do sysout in case 5, simply call the method like this

```
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("\n Your inventory is as follows: \n");
                    getPlayerInventory();
                    break;
```

Comment: Nailed it!, thanks a lot, really appreciate the help from everyone, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

If you're always returning `null` it would make sense just to make the method `void`. If `null` is printing, It sounds like you're calling this method inside a `print` method. You don't need to do that, because the inventory is already being printed inside the method.

Comment: The `println` in the loop is what is in question. What this method returns is out of scope

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).